# Coeficients in numerical calculations of exp() function

Tags: c++, c, avx2

I am trying to understand the implementation of `exp_ps()` from http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/sse_mathfun.h or `exp256_ps()` from http://software-lisc.fbk.eu/avx_mathfun/avx_mathfun.h.
I understand almost everything in the calculation, except for how constant `cephes_exp_C2` is determined. It seems that it increases the accuracy of the calculation. If it is removed from the calculation then resulting function is significantly faster and slightly less precise (relative error is still under 1% for values around +/- 10). I found such coefficients in other numerical libraries, but without closer explanation.

Comment: Code? Attempts? Examples?

Comment: I guess this constant is `exp(C2)`, where `C2` is some other constant. Do you really understand everything else? E.g. what is `cephes_exp_p0` ?

Comment: Not only you don't show any [mcve], but also dump two links to a pile of text, you don't even have a **specific** question. That's not how it works. After 3 years here you really should know [ask]!

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of searching through the [Cephes](http://www.netlib.org/cephes/) source, I think it's an error in Pommier's translation. This is not the first time I have seen errors in Pommier's code. I recommend using math library in [Gromacs](http://www.gromacs.org).

---

From `exp.c` in Cephe's,

```
static double C1 = 6.93145751953125E-1;
static double C2 = 1.42860682030941723212E-6;
....
px = floor( LOG2E * x + 0.5 );
n = px;
x -= px * C1;
x -= px * C2;
```

From Pommier,

```
_PS_CONST(cephes_exp_C1, 0.693359375);
_PS_CONST(cephes_exp_C2, -2.12194440e-4);  <-- Wrong value
....

//
//  fx = LOG2E * x + 0.5
//
fx = _mm_mul_ps(x, *(v4sf*)_ps_cephes_LOG2EF);
fx = _mm_add_ps(fx, *(v4sf*)_ps_0p5);

//
//  fx = floor(fx)
//
emm0 = _mm_cvttps_epi32(fx);
tmp  = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(emm0);
v4sf mask = _mm_cmpgt_ps(tmp, fx);    
mask = _mm_and_ps(mask, one);
fx = _mm_sub_ps(tmp, mask);

//
//  x -= fx * C1;
//  x -= fx * C2;  (Using z allows for better ILP in this step)
//
tmp = _mm_mul_ps(fx, *(v4sf*)_ps_cephes_exp_C1);
v4sf z = _mm_mul_ps(fx, *(v4sf*)_ps_cephes_exp_C2);
x = _mm_sub_ps(x, tmp);
x = _mm_sub_ps(x, z);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to cephes library, it is much better for study of implementation of basic math functions. But I still don't understand what is C2 good for. e^x is converted to e^x = e^g 2^n =e^g e^(n loge(2)) = e^(g + n loge(2)) => x = g + n loge(2) . n is calculated with floor/round function and x -= px * C1 is equivalent to g = x - n loge(2) (C1 == loge(2)). What is calculated with x -= px * C2 ? Is it somehow related to float numbers to increase the precision?